# Laravel 4, Check of route parameter exist in database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I want to check if the route parameter exist in the database table called `categories`, in that table there are two columns:

```
------------------
|   categories   |
------------------
|  id  | integer | 
| name | varchar |
------------------
```

I also have a route now:

```
Route::Get('shop/{cat}', function($cat)
{
    return View::make('products')->with('cat', $cat);
});
```

Is there a laravel function that can check if the category id `$cat` exists in the table?
If it not exist I want to redirect to the route `homepage`. Else I want to return the View: `products` 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. It is called [Route Model Bindings](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-model-binding).

To put it short, you use the `Route::bind` function to define a function to be called when evaluating the route parameters. Here is a simple example:

```
Route::bind('cat', function($value, $route)
{
    return Category::where('id', $value)->first();
});
```

Your handler will then be passed the model itself instead of the route parameter, which is quite convenient.

You can add simple logic to test if the requested model exists then take the appropriate measure. The common way would be to throw a `NotFoundException` in such case, and to handle it with the `App::missing` method. See [here](http://laravel.com/docs/errors#handling-404-errors) for more on this subject.